# How to set a background for Compiz expo plugin

Tags: compiz, appearance

Is it possible to set a background for the expo plugin instead of the reflection effect?

Comment: This old thread is pessimistic: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=980113

Comment: Yh I saw that, it doesn't look good. It just seems odd that it'd be overlooked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to set a background in the current state of the plugin. All you can do is change the background colour.

You should probably report a bug.